# How to Run Apex Scheduler 6days of job schedule?

Tags: batch

please give me one example of above scenario.how to run the schedule apex job in developer console.please give some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case you need to generate a cron expression. More on cron here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.192.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm. 
Also go through this great utility that generates cron expression on the basis of options selected on UI - http://www.cronmaker.com/ 
The answer to your question is -

```
System.schedule('BatchNotification', '0 0 9 1/6 * ? *', new BatchSxhedule());
```

here **BatchSxhedule** is your schedule class. 9 denotes the time of the day (9AM). 1/6 Denotes starting today every 6 days. 2/6 denotes starting tomorrow every six days. and so on!

Answer (score 1):

```
global class MySchedulableClass implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
            FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id =: ctx.getTriggerId()
        ];
        System.debug(ct.CronExpression);
        System.debug(ct.TimesTriggered);
        Merchandise__c m = new Merchandise__c(
            Name = 'Scheduled Job Item',
            Description__c = 'Created by the scheduler',
            Price__c = 1,
            Total_Inventory__c = 1000);
        insert m;
    }
}
```

Execute developer console....

```
MySchedulableClass  myJob = new MySchedulableClass ();
String sch = '0 0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 ? * *';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, myJob);
```